# How do we resolve the problem of tags with multiple meanings?

Tags: discussion, tags, process

This is the opposite problem of [Too many tags for d&d](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40/too-many-tags-for-dd). The specific issue which prompts it is the [[history]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag, which is currently being used to tag both questions about the history of RPGs and questions about historical settings. If this is not viewed as a problem, by all means tell me so. But assuming it is, what is the SE way to resolve it?

Of course, it's pretty easy to suggest ways of making these tags more specific. But I'm asking about the general approach to this issue - I would have thought other sites have run into this before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd remove the [history] tag and add [history-research] and [history-of-gaming]. That way, when someone types in "history", they will get prompted with the two canonical tags and can choose properly.

Comment: Thanks Adam. So just to make sure we're on the same page, the preferred approach is simply for anyone with the requisite privileges to retag all such questions (fortunately there are only 9 in the example at the moment) and, I would assume, leave a note for the OP explaining the intent?

Comment: @Dave In a case like this, I don't think that leaving a comment to the OP is even necessary unless 1) this becomes controversial; or 2) there is some possibility that changing the tag would fundamentally change the question.

Comment: I'd prefer [historical-settings] for setting research; I like [history-of-gaming]

Comment: Well I'll be happy to do the work when I have 50 more rep! I think I agree with mxyzplk on the [historical-settings] tag. Once I hear back from Adam that I've interpreted him correctly, I'll accept his answer.

Comment: OK, retagging done.

Comment: I don't like [historical-settings] because of the word "historical." If a user enters the "history" tag, we want it to auto-suggest the right tags.

Comment: @Dave Yeah, intent is understood correctly.

Comment: @Adam Thanks, answer accepted. If you want to go around and retag, I won't start a war over it. But if a user enters "history", they do still get the suggestion right up until they hit "y". I guess it could be an issue with fast typists. It depends what you value most, I guess.